# Weird noise near action bar menu after changing its background color

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menubar

This is really weird. After changing menu background color to black i've seen this bug. Looks like that's android bug. But maybe anyone knows how to solve it.

My changes for menu background color

```
<style name="CMOptionsMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/blackColor</item>
</style>

<item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/CMOptionsMenu</item>
```

I would be very thankful to you for any help.

Here's image with this weird bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Enn.png

Comment: that's Lollipop bug. Since 5.1 I haven't seen happening. It has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @Budius, i think you should write this as an answer for the question.